# wildcard mapping for classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, wildcard

Is there a way to enable wildcard mapping for selected file extensions in IIS6?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, would you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

you can have other IIS handle other extensions as if they were .asp pages.  I sometimes do this with .php to disguise my server.   Its also useful to do with .css or .xml to create dynamic .css with <% %> asp code within it.